# Guess the object - What Am I Riddle (Part 2)

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Having gotten accepted on [part 1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4182/guess-the-object-what-am-i-riddle-part-1), here I go:

Who am I? You'd like to know, so please just ask who's there,

You might have a laugh on my account, I don't really care,

If not it's still OK, that's something I can bear,

I come right out no need to guess or speculate your share.

**Edit**; Two more lines which might be sort of a giveaway, I'll leave them as a hint:

> Your cooperation is required, don't leave me out your lair,
>
>  I am right here behind the door, respond my tapping fair.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you a:

> Knock-knock joke

?

Good to see you were up to the challenge!

Comment: Very good! That was pretty quick! :) Up to continuing the chain?

Comment: Oh wow.. shot in the dark. Yeah OK I'll give it a whirl :) Starting with E?

Comment: Yeah, guess so... (sorry ;) )

Comment: @JNF http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4193/guess-the-object-what-am-i-riddle-part-3