# Guess the object - What Am I Riddle (Part 3)

Tags: word-problem, riddle, rhyme

I'm lying down, with a dah-ditty-dah, in the middle of the end,
I'd hang upside-down similarly with my friend,
Were I to flip over, with a dah-ditty-dah, it'd be the middle of the day,
Right way up I cannot plainly say,
Here's the key, let's end the fun,
I'll tell you a secret, I hide behind one

What am I?

[Part 1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4182/guess-the-object-what-am-i-riddle-part-1)
[Part 2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4186/guess-the-object-what-am-i-riddle-part-2/4190#4190)

Comment: lah-diddy-dah??

Comment: @JNF yes, it's a clue :p

Comment: i thought it was 12, because it is behind one in the clock and it is the middle of the day..but other clues don't fit...need to think harder...

Comment: that's clever. use that in another puzzle :p

Comment: Are we on the right track with the single letter idea?

Comment: yes, you are - a single character

Comment: @d'alar'cop, that'starts with the letter "e" correct?

Comment: @Mew Correct the name of the thing is a word beginning with "e"

Comment: I thought about a clock hand which doesn't begin with 'e' :p just wanted to share my thoughts

Comment: @JamesMassey I don't think the other person is going to do #4... are you interested?

Comment: I'll be able to do one tomorrow. I have my mothers birthday dinner tonight.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Answer:

> ! (**e**xclamation mark)

Explanation:

> Lying down in the "middle of the e**n**d" (n = -· in morse code)
>  Upside-down in fr**i**end
>  Flipped over in the "middle of the d**a**y" (a = ·- in morse code)
>  Right way up I cannot plainly say (one does not speak "plainly" when using '!')
>  Here's the key... Hide behind one - (think "keyboard")

Comment: With the confidence gained, please now figure out how it fits all the clues :)

Comment: I thought of this one but I couldn't get it to fit all the clues.

Comment: oh, i was thinking of that too but i cant think of how would it fit with the other clues...haha

Comment: "middle of the end" - use Morse Code clue here, same with "Middle of the day"

Comment: correct about pun (when you use "!" you are not "plainly speaking")

Comment: 'n' = dah-dit and 'a' = di-dah

Comment: @KelvinBarsana Yes, or ·- and -· (looks like side-on !/i)

Comment: Part 4: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4211/guess-the-object-what-am-i-riddle-part-4?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

The answer is

> The letter "e".
> "e" is in the middle of "th**e e**nd".
> Turn over e, and you get a, which is in the middle of the "d**a**y".
> "e" hides behind on**e**, because it is at the end.

Comment: No, sorry, that does fit the first 3 in one interpretation though... I'll add a little something

Comment: @d'alar'cop the letter e exists in the middle of "the end"

Comment: Turn "e" around, and it looks like an "a", fitting clue 3

Comment: that's an interpretation (correct in this interpretation), what about the rest of the clue?

Comment: @d'alar'cop', it hides behind "one" because e is the last letter

Comment: lol, that's yet another unexpected interpretation... what about Unlock the door?

Answer (score 3):

> is it (.) dot? its in the middle of the end of an exclamation point similarly with its friend which is (i) in upside down, you said behind 'one.' theres a dot at the end of one right? dunno with the other phrases, when a dot is assumed as the globe, when it turned upside down, it will be the middle of the day.

Comment: my friend, you right onto it... not quite the dot. recall the answer must begin with the letter E, AND fit the rest of the clue

Comment: @d'alar'cop so its not a single character? uhmm...

Comment: Well, it is.. but as word, it is not just one char

Answer (score 0):

> **N**, spelled out En

maybe?

> middle of end
>
>  upside-down - u
>
>  middle of day - noon
>
>  o**n**e
>
>  end fu**n**

**edit** - "lying down" would be

> dow**n**

Comment: how about "lying down"?

Comment: What side? where is that in the clue?

Comment: says "lying down" in the start

Comment: I see, you edited, you originally wrote "on it's side"

Comment: yes, maybe that was _too_ cryptic :(

Comment: edited in (for the spoiler tag)

Answer (score -1):

> The letter 'n' it's the middle of end, and turn it upside down it's a 'u'.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but how about the rest of the clues?

Comment: @JNF beat me to the rest of them