# A Puzzle With Weird Genii Making Deli Meat

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

<sub>Part of the [Community Metapuzzle](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5588/community-metapuzzle). The word in the puzzle below is also the word needed [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45927/community-metapuzzle-the-broken-time-machine).</sub>

---

I received a very odd communication this morning. When I got up, I found a letter on the kitchen table. It wasn't there last night. The doors were all still locked and the windows latched. I heard nothing although I am a very light sleeper.

When I picked up the letter, I saw that it had no stamp - I hadn't expected to see one - only a stylized capital Q in the upper left corner and in the center, the words I have used in the title: "Weird Genii Making Deli Meat".

Inside was a single sheet of what I believe to be papyrus. The poem that appears below was written on it in reddish-brown ink using a brush of some sort.

I know humn went much deeper into the time and space travel aspect of the community meta-puzzle than the rest of us. I can only assume that he has discovered some of the dread secrets from which Deusovi tried to protect us. I believe the poem was written in ancient Egypt. I have no theory regarding the envelope. I can only pray humn returns safely to this time and place. I believe also that it is, was, or will be his wish that this poem be published as part of the community meta-puzzle. I hope I am doing the right thing.

> It's a piece of a code round a man with a gun.
>   More than half a grand grand of it, isn't that fun?
>   It is found in your fist and the glove of a fox
>   And this pie piece, I've heard, is no stranger to socks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the answer is

> DIGIT.

Firstly, the title:

> Weir**d** Geni**i** Makin**g** Del**i** Mea**t**.

As soon as I saw the word "genii", I suspected that

> final letters of words would be required somewhere along the line -- that word was clearly chosen because it's one of relatively few English words which end in I

-- and I was not disappointed!

---

> a stylized capital Q in the upper left corner

This just refers to [humn](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18129/humn)'s avatar:

[image: humn]

The whole business of talking about humn in the question also appears not to be part of the puzzle, but simply a reference to the fact that humn was originally supposed to contribute to the community metapuzzle but was unable to, and so you've valiantly stepped up to take his place.

---

*It's a piece of a code round a man with a gun.*

> This is probably a wordplay clue of some sort, the 'round' cluing us to put one word around another to get DIGIT? **Edit:** yes indeed, it's DI(GI)T: "dit" as in the [dits and dahs](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/4193/5373) of Morse code, GI as in a [US soldier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G.I._(military)).

*More than half a grand grand of it, isn't that fun?*

> A grand is slang for a thousand, so half a grand grand is 500,000. Not sure what that has to do with digits though, except that it's got six of them. **Edit:** DI is "more than half a grand" in Roman numerals, and "grand of it" --> G+IT. Also "isn't that fun?" could be a reference to "dig it?"

*It is found in your fist and the glove of a fox*

> Digits (fingers) are in a fist, and foxgloves are also called [**digit**alis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digitalis).

*And this pie piece, I've heard, is no stranger to socks!*

> Something to do with pi(e) being irrational with infinitely many digits?

<sub>Thanks to @GarethMcCaughan for some help with the riddle - specifically, both **edit**s above.</sub>

Comment: First line: DI(GI)T; think Morse.

Comment: @Gareth That's the sort of thing I was looking for, but what's a GI?

Comment: Second line: DI (more than half a grand) G (grand) + IT; and "dig it" ~= "isn't that fun?".

Comment: A GI is an American soldier.

Comment: Last line: maybe "pie piece, I've heard" = "pi piece" = one digit of pi (which I think was also your interpretation) and "no stranger to socks" just because toes are digits too?

Comment: @Gareth Thanks! I'd never heard the term GI before.

Comment: Shall I remove my comments above now that you've updated your answer, so as to be less in the face of later solvers who might prefer to remain unspoiled?

Comment: @Gareth I dunno, it seems fair to leave your contributions visible. And by the time anyone scrolls down this far, they've probably looked at at least some of my answer anyway. On the other hand, I have credited you in my answer ... *shrug* It's up to you.

Comment: OK. I'll leave them there. (I have a general preference for not erasing history.)

Comment: Correct. The flavor text was a last minute idea to save Deusovi from having to alter his diagram.