# Guess The Object - What Am I Riddle (Part 4!)

Tags: riddle

> I am something that everyone needs.
>   You use me many times in different ways.
>   Sometimes you only use part of me,
>   Others you only use most of me.
>
> You always turn and bend me to your will.
>   You use to me to scare, to confuse, even to question.
>   You can even use to confront someone like when you say "Bill, [rest of confrontation]"
>   You absolutely use me every day.
>
> What am I?

You guys don't mind I made a part 4 do you?

The original question by https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4951/james-massey answered by https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4317/jnf can be found here: [Guess the object - What Am I Riddle (Part 1)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4182/guess-the-object-what-am-i-riddle-part-1)

The latest (other than mine) by https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2484/dalarcop answered by https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2153/kami can be found at [Guess the object - What Am I Riddle (Part 3)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4193/guess-the-object-what-am-i-riddle-part-3)

The others can be found in this list:

Part 2 by https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4317/jnf: [Guess the object - What Am I Riddle (Part 2)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4186/guess-the-object-what-am-i-riddle-part-2)

Comment: Course not. Everyone is welcome

Comment: Does it start with the previous answers letter? If not make sure you say so

Comment: What's the previous letter?

Comment: Doesn't matter, it was an arbitrary restriction

Comment: And I hereby lift the arbitrary last letter answer restriction because it's arbitrary and I have a really good one for something beginning with 't' that I want to post.

Comment: @JamesMassey Also, it's harder without that clue (which is good)

Comment: Is the riddle still valid if read by a monk? If so, that should eliminate quite a lot of answers as they don't speak everyday.

Comment: @JamesMassey Is it breakfast? My breakfast always starts with 't'...

Comment: @Niet Toast? XD

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think it's:

> The exclamation point!

My reasoning:

I am something that everyone needs.
You use me many times in different ways.

> Everyone uses it, and for a variety of reasons. Linguistics, coding, etc.

Sometimes you only use part of me,

> The dot at the bottom is a period.

Others you only use most of me.

> A vertical line by itself can be an L, pipe (|), or a 1.

You always turn and bend me to your will.
You use to me to scare, to confuse, even to question.

> Turn it upside down and it makes a lower case i, which appears in "will". Turn it on its side and it becomes Morse code for A (`._`) or N (`_.`). You can bend it into the shape of a question mark (?) or a lower case j. There are lots of reasons and ways to use an exclamation point, so you can shape it to fit your meaning ("bend it to your will"), both literally and figuratively. An exclamation can be used to scare, confuse, and (rhetorically) question.

You can even use to confront someone like when you say "Bill, [rest of confrontation]"

> We speak with passion during confrontations, calling for this punctuation mark.

You absolutely use me every day.

> We all get excited or emphatic when speaking sometimes, and of course we use it to make spoiler tags for answers posted here on Puzzling.

And finally...

> There's [this comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4211/guess-the-object-what-am-i-riddle-part-4?rq=1#comment12270_4228), though I thought of this as the answer before I saw it.

---

Turning my original answer on its head, a stronger possibility is:

> The letter i

I am something that everyone needs.
You use me many times in different ways.

> "Eye" is pronounced the same as "i". "Everyone" contains "eye" and "different ways" contains both "eye" and "i". Everyone needs both the letter i and their eyes, and uses them frequently for various purposes.

Sometimes you only use part of me,
Others you only use most of me.

> What I said about the shape of the exclamation point applies here as well, but there's more. How much of your eyes you show varies with circumstance (squinting, winking, etc.; the size of your pupil depends on the amount of light) and emotion (surprise, sleepiness, etc.)

You always turn and bend me to your will.
You use to me to scare, to confuse, even to question.

> All the reasoning about the shape of the exclamation point applies here as well; you can get lots of utility and different meanings out of this shape ("i" or "!"). But you can also use your eyes to express the emotions mentioned. You do this by moving or reshaping them ("turn and bend"), and this can express your desires or feelings ("will").

You can even use to confront someone like when you say "Bill, [rest of confrontation]"

> "Bill" contains "i", and the rest of the confrontation is likely to involve some statement like "I know..." as well as angry looks.

You absolutely use me every day.

> You use both your eyes and "i" every day, and "every" contains "eye".

And regarding the hints given in comments:

> [This statement](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4211/guess-the-object-what-am-i-riddle-part-4?rq=1#comment12270_4228) holds true for "i".

Comment: You're so close... What about bending and turning?

Comment: @warspyking I've added more reasoning in that direction, but the answer remains unchanged.

Comment: All that's keft is one crucial part with Bending...

Comment: If you bend ? What can you make?

Comment: @warspyking letter j?

Comment: If you bend the ! Sign what can you make?

Comment: @warspyking You can bend it into a question mark (?), like I added after your first comment. I suppose that could fit the clues as well, though not your comment on Kate's answer. You could also make the letter j or a semicolon (;), but those don't fit the clues well enough. Your comments about bending have led me to come up with something else (added to the answer), though I don't think it's what you're hinting at.

Comment: Combined this is perfect!

Comment: Part 5: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4240/guess-the-object-what-am-i-riddle-part-5?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

Is it..

> Words ?

I am something that everyone needs.

> technically doesn't fit since you can be alive without needing Words but i'd say its fairly nessesary in everyday Life. even mute people can use Words with sign language, Stephen Hawking has a computer etc.

You use me many times in different ways.

> Fairly self explanatory since you can use a lot of Words in different ways (to explain, express feeling etc).

Sometimes you only use part of me,

> You can abbreviate Words for example, lol, nvm, which are parts of a word or multiple Words.

Others you only use most of me.

> This one is also very self explanatory in relation to my answer

You always turn and bend me to your will.

> You can bend different Words as you probably already know.

You use to me to scare, to confuse, even to question.

> Also very self explanatory. scary stories, police questioning etc.

You can even use to confront someone like when you say "Bill, [rest of confrontation]"

> Surely if you want to confront someones its better to use Words than, for example, violence

You absolutely use me every day.

> This one is probably the least fitting but also fairly self explanatory. in relation to my own Life i seem to use Words every day.

It isn't the right answer but i felt like it could fit all of these

Answer (score 3):

> Punctuation

The "bend and twist" so close to "question" was the key for me.

I am something that everyone needs.
 You use me many times in different ways.

> Punctuation is used in a variety of ways by just about everyone

Sometimes you only use part of me,
 Others you only use most of me.

> Some punctuation marks are part of others - for example comma is part of semicolon, or dot is part of question mark or exclamation mark

You always turn and bend me to your will.
 You use to me to scare, to confuse, even to question.

> A question mark is bent. Exclamation marks are used in scary sentences like Eek! A ghost! and of course question marks are used to question

You can even use to confront someone like when you say "Bill, [rest of confrontation]"

> The sample sentence contains a comma

You absolutely use me every day.

> As above, we use punctuation every day

Note: even though in a comment the OP has indicated a more specific answer is correct, I'm adding the reasoning to this one as requested.

Comment: Oh so close! I even used it in this comment!

Comment: you mean it's the same as part 3, @warspyking?

Comment: Sort of. In a way.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is the

> Brain

Sometimes you only use part of me,
Others you only use most of me.

> Women and Men are known to use differently the brain. If I remember correctly women use normally only an emisphere

You always turn and bend me to your will.

> Will comes from brain :)

"Bill, [rest of confrontation]"

> "use your brain!"

Answer (score 2):

Are you:

> Language

I am something that everyone needs.

> Thinking and living in society requires some kind of language.

You use me many times in different ways.

> We use language at almost all times and we have apply it to everything.

Sometimes you only use part of me,
Others you only use most of me.

> We vary quite dramatically with what subsets of which languages we use.

You always turn and bend me to your will.

> Language is at our mercy regarding usage. Anything goes - better if understood by others normally.

You use to me to scare, to confuse, even to question.

> You can express emotions and intent - and prvoke emotions - using language.

You can even use to confront someone like when you say "Bill, [rest of confrontation]"

> Same as last.

You absolutely use me every day.

> Indeed, language is a mainstay of the human mind.

Answer (score 2):

My guess:

> A tongue. It bends and sometimes you don't use all of it. You speak with it so u can question, scare and confuse. It fits.

Comment: These answers are all so good!

Answer (score 0):

> You are "YOU" or "U"

It fits almost all the clues.

> I am something that everyone needs. (During Conversations)
> You use me many times in different ways. (You, U, or even with different meanings, like 'You?'- as a question, Shouting 'YOU' angrily etc)
> Sometimes you only use part of me, (Short version of You - 'U')
> Others you only use most of me. (Full 'You')
> You always turn and bend me to your will. (Rotating 'U' 90 degree clockwise will give C, and rotating 180 degrees give 'n' and if we bend 'U' more it will become 'O')
> You use to me to scare, to confuse, even to question. ('You?'-question, 'You!'-confuse,'YOU!!$$'-scare etc)
> You can even use to confront someone like when you say "Bill, [rest of confrontation]" (Bill, its You!!)
> You absolutely use me every day. (No doubt that we use You many times everyday)

Comment: Why the down vote? Is there any specific reason, so that I can improve and fix the answer. At least you can comment the reason or edit the answer after down voting.

Answer (score 0):

> finger

Everyone more or less needs them and can use them many times in different ways. You sometimes only use a part, such as the fingertip or fingerprint, sometimes use most of it. You can bend your finger at will. You can use to scare, confuse and question with gesture, i.e. the Middle Finger, air quotes etc, and confront people by pointing at them and you absolutely use them everyday. Seems to fit every part to me.

Answer (score -1):

It must be:

> Money

I am something that everyone needs.

> Do I need to explain more?.

You use me many times in different ways.

> You spend money to buy whatever you need (in different ways).

Sometimes you only use part of me,

> You spend part of your money.

Others you only use most of me.

> You spend all you have to buy expensive staff.

You always turn and bend me to your will.

> You can fold money, bend it, turn it....

You use to me to scare, to confuse, even to question.

> Use your imagination, you can use money to scare, confuse, question either legally or illegally.

You can even use to confront someone like when you say "Bill, [rest of confrontation]"

> This one is probably need some more imagination. e.g.: "Get all your money and get out of here." something like that...

You absolutely use me every day.

> In most cases, you need to use it everyday.

Answer (score -1):

Just a guess..

> Sentence, you use it everyday, you change its meaning by the way you speak, you can change it to being narrative, imperative etc.