# Guess The Object - What Am I Riddle (Part 5)

Tags: word-problem, riddle

Since part 4 is dragging it's feet, What am I?

> Puny mortals, I control your very lives!
>   When I'm angry, you cease motion, 
>   but yield to my envy, 
>   Without me you descend into chaos, 
>   I am never wrong, only long 
>   Turn from me at your peril.

Hint:

> In the city you see me every day.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> A traffic light: angry (red) means stop, envy (green) means go

Comment: Part 6: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4280/what-am-i-riddle-part-6?rq=1