# What Am I Riddle (Part 6)

Tags: riddle

Am I real? It's up to you..
I am real, if you flip me..
But, once you flip, I may bite you...

If I spit a 'POLO', I will become a little good..
If I split a 'POLO', I will become a little more good..
If I swallow a 'POLO', I will become fully good...

Can you guess who I am???

**Hint:**

> [A Polo is approximately 1.9 cm in diameter, 0.4 cm deep and has a 0.8 cm wide hole. The original Polo is white in colour with a hole in the middle, and the word 'POLO' embossed twice on one side around the ring, hence the popular slogan The Mint with the Hole.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polo_(confectionery))

---

*Note: Please place your answers in spoiler tags. Also mention how you get to the answer.*

Comment: Why the down vote? Is there any specific reason, so that I can improve and fix the question. At least you can comment the reason or edit the question after down voting.

Comment: I'm just hoping that the 'POLO' isn't a red herring. Here in the states, they're identical to Lifesavers candy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> GOD. 
>  Whether [a] God is real is up to personal belief. If flipped, it becomes "dog", which is something that is definitely real and can bite you. 
>  A Polo looks like the letter "O". I don't know what the lines about spitting or splitting a 'POLO' refer to, but if "god" "swallows" an O, it becomes "good", which is certainly fully good.

Comment: Spitting a 'POLO' means removing 'O' from GOD and it will become 'GD' or 'gd' which is an abbreviation of 'good'. Splitting a 'POLO' means, cutting 'O' in half and the lower half will appear as 'U'. So it will become 'GUD' or 'gud' which is another abbreviation of 'good' and is more closer to it. For reference go to http://www.allacronyms.com/good/abbreviated

Comment: Part 7: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4356/what-am-i-riddle-part-7?rq=1