# What Am I - Riddle Part 7

Tags: riddle, word-problem

In one form I am very tall, in another, elegant 
In one form I am happiness, in another, an eyesore 
In one form I am metal, in another, paper 
In one form Sasaki's lament, in another Greek ingenuity
In one form I am kung-fu, in another I am strong and static.

What am I?

As usual, please post your answer in spoiler tags. For bonus magical unicorn points, what does each line mean.

Hint:

> Sasaki is the last name of a famous Japanese girl.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> A crane?
>
> - The machine is tall, the animal, elegant
>
>   I’m not sure about happiness, but metal cranes are eyesores
>
>   Metal cranes, paper cranes
>
>   [Sadako Sasaki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sadako_Sasaki)
>
>   Surely there’s some kung-fu crane thing. Or maybe not. And again, the machine is strong and static – or maybe this refers to something else?

Comment: Well done! Did the hint give it away? Cranes (the bird) were an inspiration for the creation of kung-fu and embody happiness and youthfulness in Chinese culture.

Comment: @JamesMassey: No, just “Sasaki”. I’ve folded plenty of cranes at school… =)